# redirect main domain to subdomain manually select by visitor

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, cookies, subdomain

I have two wordpress website. One installed in main domain and another one installed in sub-domain under main domain. I'm doing this to manage 2 different language. I know there are so many plugins to manage multi language in site. But I have to do this manually.

But now i need to done a small job. I want to show a notification when any visitor will visit my main site for the 1st time. There I'll give 2 Language option to choose.

```
Option-1 Language English for main domain. (example.com)
Option-2 Language Spanish for Sub domain. (sp.example.com)
```

When visitor will select `Option-1` he will stay in `main site(domain)`. If he select `Option-2` then he will be redirected to the `another site(sub-domain)` and after this it'll happen automatically every time he visits

### main site(domain)

. But visitor can manually come back to main domain from sub-domain.

Any solution will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can do this job by Cookie. I am assuming that your default landing domain is English one.

In functions.php of English domain write following code

```
add_action('init','is_new_visitor');
$is_new_visitor = false;
function is_new_visitor(){
    check_new_visitor();
    set_new_visitor();
}

function check_new_visitor(){
  global $is_new_visitor;

  //check if cookie set
  if(isset($_COOKIE['new_visitor_lang']) && 
    in_array($_COOKIE['new_visitor_lang'],array('en','sp'))){

       $lang = $_COOKIE['new_visitor_lang'];  // get cookie value

       //if language is spanish then redirect user to spanish site
       if($lang=="sp"){
            wp_redirect('spanish lang domain');
            exit;
       }

  }else{

      //set global variable to true if it is new visitor
      $is_new_visitor = true;
  }
}

function set_new_visitor(){

   // check the get param and redirect user to selected domain
   if(isset($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang'],array('en','sp'))){
         setcookie( "new_visitor_lang", $_GET['lang'], time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60) );
          if($lang=="sp"){
            wp_redirect('spanish lang domain');
            exit;
       }
   }
}
```

Now where you have to show the links, add following code (Some where in header.php)

```
global $is_new_visitor;
if($is_new_visitor){


    echo  '<a href="?lang=en">English</a>';
    echo  '<a href="?lang=sp">Spanish</a>';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But my problem not yet solved. It's given me error. [ Fatal error: Cannot redeclare check_new_visitor() (previously declared in /home/*** ]. I add 1st code into my theme "functions.php" file. Then I added my 2nd code into my theme "header.php" file inside PHP tag. And after that getting this error. please explain me. I've not good knowledge on coding.

Comment: Change the first section for the functions.php file from: `add_action('init','check_new_visitor');
$is_new_visitor = false;
function check_new_visitor(){
    check_new_visitor();
    set_new_visitor();
}
` to `add_action('init','check_visitor');
$is_new_visitor = false;
function check_visitor(){
    check_new_visitor();
    set_new_visitor();
}
`

Comment: @Daniel Cooley I edited this as per your instruction. This time no error found but not result also.

Comment: @HASNAT can you check if this cookie new_visitor_lang set in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a pop up asking which version they want to see, and two buttons, or links, to take them to the appropriate site... you can use jQuery or plain JavaScript:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
    var $days = 30;
    var $date = new Date();
    $date.setTime($date.getTime() + ($days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var $expires = "; expires=" + $date.toGMTString() + '; path=/';
    jQuery( '#id_of_english_button' )
        .click( function( event ) {
            document.cookie = 'language=english' + $expires;
        });
    jQuery( '#id_of_spanish_button' )
        .click( function( event ) {
            document.cookie = 'language=spanish' + $expires;
        });
});
```

Then you'll have a PHP cookie variable you can work with: `$_COOKIE['language']`

Use what DarkBee had said in his comment, and do a `header('location : sub.domain.com');` to send people to the sub domain if their cookie equals 'spanish'.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your reply. I'm using wordpress site and I don't have so much knowledge on coding. so please can you explain it step by step.

Answer (score -1):

```
   /*this code write on your main site and the user will 
         automatically redirect to the subdomain  */ 
      if(!isset($_SESSION['lang'])
    {
    $_SESSION['lang']='visitor selected language';
    }

    if($_SESSION['lang']=="Option-2")
     {
   header("Location:url");
     }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me, in wordpress site where i should put this code. And is it possiable to set cookies.

Comment: imo you should use `header('location : sub.domain.com');` to relocate the user and not javascript

Comment: some wordpress templates are display header already sent output information error, so the javascript function is also used for the solution